# Regarding a Nonlinear Operator on a Cone $K$

Tags: functional-analysis, definition, nonlinear-analysis

We say that a nonlinear operator $N: E \rightarrow E $ on a Banach space $E$ is cone preserving (i.e. positive) if it maps the cone $K \subseteq E$  into itself, that is $N(K) \subseteq K$.

My question is: does $N(0)=0$? In other words, does $0$ map to $0$ under $N$? I know that if the operator is linear, then this is true. But I am not sure if it is still true for a general, nonlinear operator which is positive.

Comment: Isn't $\{0\}$ a cone? Or is $K$ a fixed cone (e.g. a positive cone under a partial order)?

Comment: Well, $\{0\}$ is closed, convex and satisfies the properties of a cone $K$ in $E$, that is if $x \in K$ then $\lambda x \in K$ if $\lambda$ is nonnegative, and $K \cap (-K) = \{0\}$.

Comment: No, $K$ is arbitrary.

Answer (score 1):

If $N$ preserves every cone, then it preserves $\{0\}$. Thus,
$$N(0) \in N(\{0\}) \subseteq \{0\} \implies N(0) = 0.$$

Comment: I see, yes this is what I wanted to say. So if $N$ is positive (not necessarily linear), then yes. Thanks.